# Participating Google TensorFlow certificate exam with M1 Mac

Tags: macos, tensorflow, apple-m1

I wanna write the exam to purchase the Google developer certificate. The handbook https://www.tensorflow.org/extras/cert/Setting_Up_TF_Developer_Certificate_Exam.pdf says that for the exam only tensorflow 2.5 is available. I run on an M1 chip so for me only tensorflow-macos is possible. Does anyone know how I could still participate. Did someone the exam with the same hardware? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you practice on Google Colab?

Comment: The exam is in PyCharm

Comment: Follow the instructions mentioned https://gist.github.com/gembin/634b4f462766a8a79c3035a85bbcd7a7.